# Can a single instance of MongoDB be used simultaneously with both .NET & PHP?

Tags: php, asp.net, .net, mongodb, database

I'd like to know if it was possible to load both drivers for MongoDB in the same database instance to be used simultaneously by two different languages (PHP & ASP.NET) on two separate platforms. A good example would be a .NET backend with a PHP frontend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**. You can have dozes of clients (written in different languages) connected to the same database as with most other database systems.

A big database wouldn't be of much fun if only one client could access it at a time.

Comment: More specifically, I wasn't sure if there would be issues with using both drivers in MongoDB at the same time. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

You don't "load the drivers into the database" - drivers are used to let a particular language talk to the database.

To answer the question, yes, you can access the same database from multiple languages/programs.

Comment: Yes, this part is understood. Thanks for clarifying that the two can be used in the same instance.